# Axios adding headers to get request only sends options

Tags: reactjs, symfony, nginx, axios

So I have a simple axios request from my reactjs component:

```
let config = {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer token-value'}};

axios.get(routes.API + '/user', config).then(response => {
    console.debug(response);
}).catch(error => {
    // error
});
```

Backend is just a simple symfony controller that accepts GET request and should return user data.

The issue is that this request only makes OPTIONS request. And it fails because my backend function is only supposed to accept get. It fails because of method not allowed. If I allow OPTIONS request method it fails, because of authorization error. And I never want to authorize OPTIONS because it would fetch user from the database.
Also it never does GET request.

If I remove config object and only leave url the request works as it should and never sends OPTIONS request, but I need header to pass my authorization token.

I have these headers enabled on my backend nginx server:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not really an axios specific behaviour, you should make sure that your server is able to handle CORS properly. For Symfony - there is a bundle that does it for you, I had to use it when having a similar issue:

https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle

Here is a sample config:

```
nelmio_cors:
  defaults:
      allow_credentials: false
      allow_origin: []
      allow_headers: []
      allow_methods: []
      expose_headers: []
      max_age: 0
      hosts: []
      origin_regex: false
      forced_allow_origin_value: ~
  paths:
      '^/api/':
          allow_origin: ['*']
          #Without this the OPTIONS request by axios won't work
          allow_headers: ['Content-Type']
          allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
          max_age: 3600
```

Comment: The issue will persist because OPTIONS request wont bypass my authorization as it does not include bearer token in it's headers and therefore won't make the GET request. I created dummy method with only OPTIONS request and excluded it from firewall which is not nice but does the job until I find the correct solution.

Comment: That bundle will bypass your firewalls unless some other bundle will hijack the response in its listener. So it doesn't really care about your authorization workflow. It's really a good permanent solution for your issue.